# Which document classes have frame and pdfpageduration type commands?

Tags: beamer

Are these effects only available in the beamer class? Are there similar commands in other packages/classes?

1/22/2012- I want to have access to basic animation tools in order to make "live" text. The only package that I know is beamer but that assumes that you want to make a power-point style or slide presentation. I want some of the same capabilities but I do not want the way beamer changes all default settings of article class.

For example consider explaining the stages of long division in an ordinary document.

Comment: What is the intention? Do you search an alternative to `beamer`

Comment: For animation tools you can use the package `animate` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at, http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st371-lindstro/hwfall02/texpower.sty, which defines some of these transitions.